# Failed to rename directory because access was denied in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Hi im trying to upgrade the version on my current flutter however i encounter this error Failed to rename directory because access was denied as i need to do changes to my system any suggestion will be appreciated.]

Hi im trying to upgrade the version on my current flutter however i encounter this error **Failed to rename directory because access was denied** as i need to do changes to my system Please take a look of my screen capture any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Generally things like this are because you have some program that's open in one of the flutter directories. Try closing things like command prompt windows, and failing that restart your computer or log in/out.

Answer (score 7):

Try running the command `flutter pub get -v`.

It shows the log and can even solve the problem.

Comment: @Volodymyr Dobryvechir not working above command for me

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. None of the answers worked. I deleted .dart_tool folder in the project folder and it worked :)

Answer (score 4):

Try to disable your antivirus for like 5 minutes and then go to the flutter directory

**C:\src\flutter**

and run the command

> *flutter pub global activate devtools*

**Note:** The flutter path should be set in env variables before running this.

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command:

```
flutter pub global activate devtools
```

Then try to get the packages again.

I hope this helps fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

When all other command don't working (in my case is my antivirus block `flutter` command), I launch in my project folder:

> /flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart
> __deprecated_pub --verbose get --no-precompile

the command stop on rename folder error.

I rename with `cp` command the folder and after the command `flutter pub get` working fine.

Answer (score 0):

run flutter pub get -v
this will show you what folder it is trying to rename to what. Manually rename the folder and place it in the path it was trying to place. re-run flutter pub get -v, repeat until it says exit with 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I proceeded to resolve that problem:

First I had to run the command bellow to see in details what he is trying to rename:

```
flutter pub get -v
```

After that in the console I searched for the term "**renaming**" and I found this:
[image]

So I had to go to the path specified in the console where flutter was installed, and I found this:
[image]

Then I deleted all the folders, and tried to run the command **flutter pub get** again. it didn't work, so I restored the deleted folders, and I tried again for the second time. And magically the command worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

After Run This Command

```
flutter pub get -v
```

Found that there is some application running in the background which is located in `%temp%` directory.

After deleting all files & folders from that directory I can able to run the command

Answer (score -1):

Do "pub cache repair"
and try "pub get"

Comment: could you be more specific